# Lock the maximum value in Python with Real time and calculated data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a code in order to Lock the profit in Case Overall profit has increased to a threshold. With the script mentioned below Locked Profit is also variable which is not desirable. I want to freeze locked profit.

```
pl_total=1000
 while pl_total <= 800:
    exit_pl=-2000
    break   
 while pl_total > 800:
    if pl_total >= 1000:
        exit_pl=500

        for i in range (1000,20000,1000):
            if pl_total > i+1000:
                exit_pl+=500
    else:
        exit_pl=-1700
    break
print (f"Profit Locked at {exit_pl}") 
if pl_total<=exit_pl:
    print("Position Closed")
```

The output calculation is OK and is expected but it changes with change in profit value which i want to freeze (Max exit_pl value)

I have tried to Randomise the value of pl_total with following code

Here is below code where i try to put random value of pl_total

```
import random
import time
while True:
    pl_total = random.randint(-2000,5000)
    time.sleep(2)
    print (f"pl_total is {pl_total}")

    while pl_total <= 800:
        exit_pl=-2000
        break   
    while pl_total > 800:
        if pl_total >= 1000:
            exit_pl=500

            for i in range (1000,20000,1000):
                if pl_total > i+1000:
                    exit_pl+=500
        else:
            exit_pl=-1700
        break
    print (f"Profit Locked at {exit_pl}") 
    if pl_total<=exit_pl:
        print("Position Closed")
```

The output of above code is pl_total is 764
Profit Locked at -2000
pl_total is 460
Profit Locked at -2000
pl_total is 1298
Profit Locked at 500
pl_total is -75
Profit Locked at -2000

I want to lock exit_pl value at 500 which is max value among the first three.

Comment: Nothing changes `pl_total` so it is always >800 so the while loop will run forever?

Comment: pl_total is input variable and will be changing every second

Comment: pl_total=1000
 while pl_total <= 800:
    exit_pl=-2000
    break   

This part will obviously never be executed because pl_total = 1000 and hence > 800. Also why do you use that many while loops in general when you break them immediately, a simple if would do the same job

Comment: pl_total is input value and it changes every second, i am using while loops as the conditions are diffrent with every pl_total threshold.

Comment: Please show the 'full' code that shows how `pl_total` changes as it is difficult to understand this code otherwise.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example of your problem

Comment: pl_total is input value derived from portfolio, you can check the above code in jupyter. I just need to Lock max value of exit_pl.

Comment: @JCaesar Here is below code where i try to put random value of pl_total

Comment: @match Pl check updated post now

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use while loops, since the value is only set once, so `if` is good enough.

Refactoring to be a function which returns, rather than trying to break, is also neater. For example:

```
import random
import time

def pl():
    while True:
        pl_total = random.randint(-2000,5000)
        time.sleep(2)
        print (f"pl_total is {pl_total}")
        # pl_total = 1298
        if pl_total <= 800:
            return (pl_total, -2000)
        else:
            if pl_total >= 1000:
                exit_pl=500
                for i in range (1000,20000,1000):
                    if pl_total > i+1000:
                        exit_pl+=500
            else:
                exit_pl = -1700
            return (pl_total, exit_pl)

pl_total, exit_pl = pl()
print (f"Profit Locked at {exit_pl}")     
if pl_total<=exit_pl:
    print("Position Closed")
```

Comment: Many Thanks for Answering this, The output of your code willl be only one time value. But i need to freeze the maximum value of the output.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you  explain better what 'freeze the maximum value' is?

Comment: I know it is a bit difficult to explain for me. Giving it a last try  
Here is the output of code which i have posted 
pl_total is 1858
Profit Locked at 500
pl_total is 3336
Profit Locked at 1500
pl_total is 2531
Profit Locked at 1000
pl_total is 2292
Profit Locked at 1000

Now the maximum of first two values is 1500, i want to freeze (Lock ) this value till a new value > 1500 comes.